# All users can write only one can read system

Tags: encryption, rsa, asymmetric

The system I want to implement has the following requirement: All users can insert some sensitive data, but only one, master user, can see it.

There is any known, already implemented solution to this issue? I have to encrypt data so without the master password is impossible to read it.

The only solution I thought about was using asymmetric encryption. The users that can write will use the public key and the master user can use its private key to read the data. The problem here is that it's impossible for the user to remember a long password (public/private key)

Thank you!

Comment: Well the master user needs access to some secret nobody else knows. Else there is nothing that distinguishes the real recipient from an attacker. Assuming you use a proper password hash, that secret 60 to 80 bits of entropy.

Comment: The senders need some way to obtain the public key of the receiver. That could be a 256 bit ECC key, or if you assume that there is public but untrusted storage, a fingerprint of 60 to 80 bits.

Comment: Let me explain the scenario a little more. There are two types of users: sellers and administrator. The sellers can sell products (thus introducing data in system), but must not be able to get the data they inserted (by any means). The administrator should be able to see, for example, the sales made in one day. Let's assume that the transmission of keys is secure.

Comment: Asymmetric encryption easily solves that part of the problem. The only remaining problem is key management - the sender must be able to obtain the public key (which requires some trust root) and the receiver needs some way to obtain their private key (either store it securely or decrypt is with a password).

Comment: Can you formulate your comments as a response? So I can reward you for the suggestion/discussion.

Comment: ...If you're just inserting this in a db, why not just design your API (or your website) so that sellers just don't get to see what they inserted?  Note that you have to do something akin to this anyways, just to keep them from reading what they just did...  You can encrypt the db if you need to  (most major ones have built-in facilities for this).  I have to ask, though, what kind of data are you inserting, that sellers shouldn't be able to read it?  If Credit Card numbers, you probably want a system that logs reads of the sensitive info (likely do anyways).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse The master user should be able to see the sensitive data in the same application. So the easy schema of encrypting using a predefined key fails.

Comment: Again, if you're going to all the trouble of maintaining all this for somebody else (most people don't know how to deal with encryption keys), just make it so that they have read permissions in your application.  You don't really need to encrypt anything at that point (even if you should for the data at rest), because the unauthorized people literally have no (legitimate) way to **get** the data.  It's actually better than handing them encrypted records, too.  If they have a illegitimate way to get the data, I'd expect they'd have a way to get non-encrypted records anyways...

Answer (score 1):

You can create it in two ways: with access control or with encryption.

**Access Control**

You create a system where the settlers can access only a *insert data* page, and don't create a page to *read data* accessible to them. This way you have the *write only* system. To actually read the data, you create another page accessible only to the *admin*, where s/he can read all the posted data.

*Pros:*

- Easy to create
- Easy to maintain
- Simple

*Cons:*

- If the information is sensitive, a database leak can be devastating
- No way to garantee the integrity of the data

**Encryption**

You create a system with one page to *settlers*, and other page for the *admin*. As soon as the data is posted by the *settler*, you encript it with a public key owned by the admin, then store the encrypted data on the database.

To read the data, the admin logs in using the special page, and gets the encrypted data in a json file, XML or csv. Then it runs the file through GPG or any other encryption software and decrypts the file.

The requirement of an external program can be solved by decrypting data locally using javascript. It's crucial to *not store* the private key in the server in any way.

*Pros:*

- Very secure
- Even a database leak will not compromise data

*Cons:*

- Adds complexity
- May require external programs

Comment: The first approach (security by obscurity) is a no-way. The second approach can be simplified if I consider the transportation secure (on the same local network). Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: @nucandrei the first approach is not security by obscurity, it's access control.  There is no way in which an attacker would gain an advantage from knowing the scheme involved.

Comment: @nucandrei Istvan is right. Even if the attacker knows the URL for the _read system_, he must authenticate itself first.